# How to merge multiple excel sheets from different workbook using google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, merge, google-sheets-formula

Most if not all of the solutions here requires a third-party platform to carry this out. Is there a way to do it **within excel sheet** itself?

Due to the privacy of content, I have multiple excel sheets being updated on different workbooks. However, I have to consolidate all of them into 1 sheet in order to analyse the trends. The 'Merge Sheet' plugin doesn't work for me. All the sheets have the same headers/columns but different amount of rows. Some of the columns have data validation formula. But it can be converted to text after merging, that's fine.

I've tried using this:
**=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url","range_string")**

This works, and updates the sheet in real time.

However, it only merges the first sheet of the workbook. I have 4 sheets in 1 workbook.

Also, whenever a new row is created in the individual sheets, I would have to insert new row in the consolidated sheet and edit "range_string" to include the new row.

Is there another formula(s) I can use **within excel** to carry out this function?
It might require more steps, but more steps is better than making 30 adjustments for quarterly updates.

I don't have conditions when merging, I just want to merge everything wholesale.

Comment: excel ≠ google sheets → its confusing when you use those terms interchangeably in your question! Use this [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) to create 2 test sheets → fill them with dummy data → link them with importrange → showcase us how you are using the formula(s) right now & also **manually enter aside** the output you ideally expect to see...

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Hi, We have a specific place for questions and answers. You can comment below my answer if you want. You can add a new answer, if you have a new answer.   You can [edit] your question, if you want to add additional information to the question or if the question is drastically different, ask a  new question. If my answer solved this question, click the checkmark on the left of my answer. Please take the [tour]

Comment: Specifically, alternatives should be a new answer and not an edit. Feel free to add a new answer with your alternative below. See [answer]

Answer (score 0):

The `range_string` in [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) can

- Specify a specific  sheet/tab  to be imported

  ```
  =IMPORTRANGE("url", "Sheet2!A1:A15")
  ```
- and be open ended

  ```
  =IMPORTRANGE("url", "A:A")
  ```